# Какие задачи можно решить используя Swift3 под Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, swift

Какие задачи на линуксе решает swift?
Для чего выпускают версию swift под ubuntu если на нем нельзя скомпилировать приложение под яблочные ОС ?

Comment: Очевидно, что для написания приложений для ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Что Вы имеете в виду под

> нельзя скомпилировать приложение под яблочные ОС

Что под iPhone не сможете собрать приложение? Тогда это так. А под macOS можно.

Открытым сделали сам язык программирования, но все остальное закрыто.
Задачи решить Вы можете те, для которых подойдет данный инструмент. Под iPhone Вы ничего не соберете, а под Linux (и macOS) можете написать, к примеру, [HTTP сервер](https://github.com/huytd/swift-http) , [Еще один сервер](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect) и [много другого](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=linux%20language%3ASwift) + все что захотите и сможете.

Также благодаря открытости стали доступны подобные [песочницы](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl), где можно писать на `Swift` на любом устройстве, у которого есть выход в интернет и ОС не играет роли.

Ну и если учесть, что его только сделали открытым, то все еще впереди.